# How to repeat the movement of gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to setup a simple "ai" system that follows the waypoint and after the last waypoint I want it to go the first waypoint. Here's what I got so far:

```
// put the points from unity interface
public Transform[] wayPointList;

public int currentWayPoint = 0; 
Transform targetWayPoint;

public float speed = 4f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
   // check if we have somewere to walk
   if(currentWayPoint < this.wayPointList.Length)
   {
       if(targetWayPoint == null)
           targetWayPoint = wayPointList[currentWayPoint];
       walk();
   }
}

void walk(){
   // rotate towards the target
   transform.forward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetWayPoint.position - transform.position, speed*Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);

   // move towards the target
   transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWayPoint.position,   speed*Time.deltaTime);

   if(transform.position == targetWayPoint.position)
   {
       currentWayPoint ++ ;
       targetWayPoint = wayPointList[currentWayPoint];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to reset when fully path is complete?

try this:

```
void walk()
{
    // rotate towards the target
    transform.forward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetWayPoint.position - transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);

    // move towards the target
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWayPoint.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position == targetWayPoint.position)
    {
        if (currentWayPoint == this.wayPointList.Length-1)
            currentWayPoint = 0;
        else
            currentWayPoint++;
        targetWayPoint = wayPointList[currentWayPoint];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do currentWaypoint = (currentWaypoint  + 1) % totalWaypoints;